# How can I export inline translations to another Magento store?

Tags: php, csv, internationalization, magento, translation

I need to export all translations from the main store to another.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Export the contents of the `core_translate` table in the database.  You can use phpmyadmin for that.

Comment: any suggestions to pass these translations into a CSV file? thanks

Comment: are you asking specifically about the CSV files used by Magento's translate function, or a generic CSV file?  Within phpMyAdmin, if you navigate to the `core_translate` table, then click the Export tab, you can select CSV as the export format.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/ceefour/translation_exporter

This extension could do the job you expected.